# Comandos de um SVG path em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

Estou tentando criar um gráfico de linhas baseado nos valores inseridos por um usuário no campo input do HTML, mas estou com dificuldades em converter os comandos do elemento SVG para JavaScript.

Como posso fazer a conversão? Preciso que quando o usuário insira o valor, ele aparecerá no gráfico dinamicamente.

```
 function line() {
    var svgElement = document.getElementById('svgCanvas');
    let data = new Array();
    data[0] = document.getElementById('data1').value;
    data[1] = document.getElementById('data2').value;
    data[2] = document.getElementById('data3').value;
    data[3] = document.getElementById('data4').value;
    data[4] = document.getElementById('data5').value;
    data[5] = document.getElementById('data6').value;

    let index=0;
    let dx;
    dx += 20;

    var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d','M 100,0' + 
                      'L' + dx + data[0] + 
                      'L' + dx + data[1] +  
                      'L' + dx + data[2] +  
                      'L' + dx + data[3] + 
                      'L' + dx + data[4] +  
                      'L' + dx + data[5] + 
                      'L' + dx + data[6]
                      );
    path.setAttribute('stroke','red');
    path.setAttribute('fill','none');
    path.setAttribute('stroke-width', 5);
    svgElement.appendChild(path);
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço enormemente.

Answer (score 0):

Tinha alguns erros no código.

A variável `dx` estava sendo inicializada sem valor e em seguida você
   a incrementava em 20 o que resultava em `NaN`:

```
let dx;
dx += 20; // dx é igual a NaN
```

Faltou dar espaços entre entre as coordenadas dos pontos da linha.

Havia o uso do elemento do array `data` de índice `6` cujo o valor era `null`.

```js
function line() {
  var svgElement = document.getElementById('svgCanvas');
  let data = new Array();
  data[0] = document.getElementById('data1').value;
  data[1] = document.getElementById('data2').value;
  data[2] = document.getElementById('data3').value;
  data[3] = document.getElementById('data4').value;
  data[4] = document.getElementById('data5').value;
  data[5] = document.getElementById('data6').value;

  let index = 0;
  let dx = 20;

  var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  path.setAttribute('d', 'M 100 0' +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[0] +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[1] +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[2] +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[3] +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[4] +
    ' L ' + dx + ' ' + data[5]        
  );
  path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
  path.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
  path.setAttribute('stroke-width', 5);
  svgElement.appendChild(path);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgCanvas">

</svg><br>

<span>data1:</span><input type="number" id="data1" value="0"><br>
<span>data2:</span><input type="number" id="data2" value="0"><br>
<span>data3:</span><input type="number" id="data3" value="0"><br>
<span>data4:</span><input type="number" id="data4" value="0"><br>
<span>data5:</span><input type="number" id="data5" value="0"><br>
<span>data6:</span><input type="number" id="data6" value="0"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="line()">Linha</button>
```